# Sending value, get nothing

Tags: php, ajax

I created ajax function which sends data to php file but something is wrong because when i die it, it holds nothing, and i know that my ajax function was written good. Here is how am i sending it:

```
xmlhttp.send(dop);
```

And here is how i recieve it in php file:

```
$selectedLang = isset($_POST['dop']) ? $_POST['dop'] : '';
```

What am i doing wrong? I'am probably recieving info badly. Coz i can see that parameteres are good in ajax function. Please help, really need fast.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function run()
    {
        var dop = document.getElementById("kalba").value;
        return dop;
    }
    function insertData()
    {
        var dop = run();
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","style/wps-light/datafile.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("Reiksme=" + encodeURIComponent(dop));
    }
</script>
```

datafile.php:

```
<?php
$selectedLang = isset($_POST['dop']) ? $_POST['dop'] : '';
die("Viskas ok $selectedLang");

?>
```

Comment: can you show what `dop` contains? Have you set `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader`?

Comment: Show full code, really need fast.

Comment: Updated. dop is value of the select option

Comment: And what happens in `datafile.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get it like that:

```
$selectedLang = isset($_POST['Reiksme']) ? $_POST['Reiksme'] : '';
```

Because `Reiksme` is the key in `$_POST` array, not `dop`:

```
xmlhttp.send("Reiksme=" + encodeURIComponent(dop));
              ^^^^^^^
```